# How to find the exactly result ONLY selected node in tree sql for DB2?

Tags: sql, tree, db2

i have the two table.That is Table A and Table B.

```
Table A
---------------------------------------------------------------------
REFEV_VEH_TYPE |REFEV_CATEGORY  |REFEV_USAGE    |REFEV_BODY_CODE|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
03                       T            BN               SKS
03                       T            BN               SKL
03                       T            BN               SKH
03                       T            BN               SKD
03                       T            BN               SKA
03                       T            BN               SJR
03                       T            BN               DOP
03                       T            BN               STP
03                       T            BN               STN
03                       D            BH               PTU
03                       D            BH               LRT
03                       D            BH               JTU
03                       D            BB               LRT
03                       D            BJ               LRT
03                       D            BX               LRT
02                       C            AK               VAN
02                       C            AK               PIC
02                       C            AK               MUV
02                       C            AK               MKR
02                       C            AK               JIP
02                       D            JH               PTU
02                       D            JG               PTU
02                       D            JF               PTU
02                       D            JB               PTU
02                       D            BK               LRT
02                       D            BK               JTU
02                       D            AK               PTU
02                       M            AK               TWR
02                       M            AK               MSP
02                       M            AK               MSL
02                       M            AK               MSB
04                       D            BT               LRT    
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table B

```
-----------------
|REFEV_USAGE |BilUsg |
|-------     |-------|
|BN          |1      |
|BH          |5      |
|BJ          |45     |
|BX          |12     |
|AK          |15     |
|AK          |36     |
|JH          |34     |
|JG          |56     |   
----------------------
```

The table A and Table B will join use the REFEV_USAGE .

```
For Example:-

if i want to choose the result:-

RESULT 1
-i choose the REFEV_VEH_TYPE=> '03' and REFEV_USAGE=>'BT' from Table A, 
so i just want only what i choose appear in my result

-------------------------------------------------------------
|REFEV_VEH_TYPE|REFEV_USAGE|REFEV_CATEGORY  |REFEV_BODY_CODE|
|--------------|-----------|---------------------------------
|03            |BT         |


RESULT 2
- i choose the REFEV_USAGE=>'BH' from Table A

---------
|REFEV_VEH_TYPE|REFEV_USAGE|REFEV_CATEGORY  |REFEV_BODY_CODE|
-------------------------------------------------------------
                    BH
```

RESULT 3
    - i choose the REFEV_VEH_TYPE=>'02','03' ,REFEV_CATEGORY=>('T','D') ,REFEV_VEH_TYPE=>'BJ' from Table A and join use usgType to Table B and i       choose REFEV_VEH_TYPE=>'BJ' and BilUsg=>'45'

---

```
REFEV_VEH_TYPE  |REFEV_CATEGORY     |REFEV_USAGE    |BilUsg |
|---------------|-------------------|---------------|-------|
|03             |'T'                |BJ             | 45    |
|02             |'D'                |               |       |
```

Anyone know how to choose ONLY the selected node data that i select appear in query result?

Comment: There isn't a good/easy way to change what **columns** you get out of the same statement by putting in different input.  You'd be better off writing multiple statements.  Next, SQL is a set-based language, which means it wants to return _all_ rows which match some condition, unless you give it an `ORDER BY` and then (in DB2) a `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW`.  What is it you're really trying to accomplish here?  What's the big-picture task.

Comment: ok.but i have no idea about that because my query is about the tree structure.My screen java display the tree structure. i don't know how to display the result according the ONLY data that i selected in my tree. do you have any idea. i'm so confuse about that because this first time i get this task.:(

Comment: Currently you don't really have a tree structure as such...

Comment: oh i see. but how do you know whether the table is tree structure or not?.And what the problem with my table A and B?

Comment: A tree is something that has parent and child elements - this just appears to be a multi-column key.  If you write a statement like `SELECT <columns> FROM <table_a> WHERE REFEV_VEH_TYPE = 03`, it's going to give you back multiple rows.  And you generally can't/shouldn't mix statements that output different columns in their result set.  Some of your problems may be better dealt with Java-side.